# Submitting data to two mysql tables using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Is it possible to submit data to two tables with the same query?

My existing code looks like this:

```
private function adduser() {

    if (!empty($this->error)) return false;

    $params = array(
        ':user_level' => parent::getOption('default-level'),
        ':name'       => $this->name,
        ':email'      => $this->email,
        ':username'   => $this->username,
        ':password'   => parent::hashPassword($this->password)
    );

    parent::query("INSERT INTO `login_users` (`user_level`, `name`, `email`, `username`, `password`)
                    VALUES (:user_level, :name, :email, :username, :password);", $params);
```

I didn't write this code so it is a bit confusing to me as I don't usually use PDO.  What I would like to do in addition to this is add two values to my 'url_alias' table, the first is the UID (which is auto incremented from the first query) and the second is another variable value.

All of the examples I have found while searching dont seem to work for me because of the way this existing code looks.

Can anyone give me a hand?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter what db driver your are using (PDO, Mysqli, etc.) you question is purely about mysql capabilities. Mysql may update and delete rows from multiple tables in a single query but not insert. I.e. `INSERT table_1, table_2 ...` is not allowed.

You have to run one query for each table you want to insert data.

Comment: Is it possible to use transactions or something to submit the second query?

Comment: Sure you can use transactions. Begin one, run the queries you need and finally commit the transaction.

Comment: How do you use transactions when a query starts like "parent::query"  non of the example I found online seem to fit the code I have already

Comment: `parent::beginTransaction();` `::` is the scope operator. You are calling `query()` of the parent class. I presume the parent class is a PDO. Have a look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php